# Which's the best DB(NoSQL or regular SQL) to choose using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mongodb, serverside-javascript

I've read that there are more information about using MongoDB with Node.js rather than MySQL and that is a concern for me, because I'm used to work with MySQL. In terms of development and performance which one is the best option?

Comment: You should still find enough information with the libraries -- [`mysql`](https://npmjs.org/package/mysql), [`sequelize`](https://npmjs.org/package/sequelize), [etc](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/mysql). What's "*best*" mostly depends on your needs, as they're both capable and performant platforms. If you think MySQL will serve you well, then go with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not using sql or using sql is not really the question you're asking, as all none sql databases are not sql :)

You're looking at RDBMS (SQL,ORALCE, etc) which have relationships and normalization and vs noSQL database, and the answer is that it really depends on what you need, there is not one perfect one for Node.js, it's a matter of preference and need.

Document based noSQL (like CouchDB/MonogoDB/Redis) base their speed on tailing the de-normalization of the database to fit your queries. 
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#database

Here are some popular ones:
Some popular ones include:

1. MongoDB
2. Redis
3. Couch
4. Riak

Again there is no one answer to fit them all however here is an excellent article on this matter:
http://slashdot.org/topic/bi/sql-vs-nosql-which-is-better/

Answer (score 1):

Choice between MySQL and MongoDB is a question of architecture and depends on the nature of your data: do you need the constrains and transactions, joins and other features of SQL engines, or your data is not normalized and you don't have a lot of references between them and your schema is not stable.

From technology viewpoint Node.js and MongoDB is a good choice in matter of using one technology stack for back-end and persistent storage. MongoDB keeps data in a [bson format](http://bsonspec.org/) which is easily converted to json without additional layers and is a natural data format for javascript.

More information about pros and cons you can find [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/)